# Easiest way to use a managed library in Unity3d that's part of the solution

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity creates solution for UWP (hololens actually, not sure if it matters).

Most of my work is done on a class library that contains my logic. I want to call from the unity C# scripts into this class library I am using. Since the Assembly-csharp DLL gets recreated completely every time, I obviously can't just add a project reference in there.

What's the best way to achieve this?

What I've found so far is that I can pull the actual DLL binary of my library DLL into the Unity Assets folder, at which point it actually does get referenced in the Assembly-csharp project - however - the DLL actually gets copied to a separate location (\Unprocessed\MyLibrary.dll). That means I need to copy my project there everytime I make a change (or re-publish from Unity which takes a bunch of time).

I know I can have a post-build stage that will copy the file - however - is there any more "correct" way? The way this works now (dropping a DLL into the Assets) also has other disadvantages such as making building a certain flavor much harder than it should be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way: you put the library DLL in Unity's Asset folder, and never touch the generated C# project.

Consider that in most common scenarios, *both the library itself and the Unity code referencing it would change* so a rebuild of the Unity project is a natural part of the process. If that takes too much time, it is usually advisable to create a dedicated, smaller Unity project to quickly iterate through the DLL development cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really need to rebuild unity to make changes to script, so in many cases, as long as I don't touch the default scene or whatever, I can just make changes in the scripts directly in VS and not have to rebuild unity (which then requires I reload VS etc). But if this is the way to go, then this is the way to go. Thanks again.